# Hide/Show content using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, setstate

I am trying to implement to Show More/Show Less. So far I have was able to bring up a ItemViewer Component where in I display the list of items. For each section there would be Show More / Show Less links. Show More should be visible whenever the number of items is greater than 3 and it should be able to toggle(Show More/ Show Less). When the number of items is less than 3 dont show the link. Also when there is no data display "No data found".

I have come up with a sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-kirch-1fgq3

Can someone help me here?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ItemViewer from "./Item";

const item1 = ["i1d1", "i2d2", "i3d3"];
const item2 = ["i2d1", "i2d2", "i2d3", "i2d4"];
const item3 = ["i3d1", "i3d2", "i3d3", "i3d4", "i3d5"];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      item1: [],
      item2: [],
      item3: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      item1,
      item2,
      item3
    });
  }

  render() {
    let { item1, item2, item3 } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <ItemViewer index="1" item="item1" itemData={item1} />
        <ItemViewer index="2" item="item2" itemData={item2} />
        <ItemViewer index="3" item="item3" itemData={item3} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const ItemViewer = props => {
  function renderItems(list, itemType) {
    if (list && list.length > 0) {
      return (
        <>
          <ul>
            {list.map(function(item) {
              return <li key={item}>{item}</li>;
            })}
          </ul>
        </>
      );
    } else {
      return <p>No Items Found</p>;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <span>
        {props.index}: {props.item}
      </span>
      <div>
        <a href="#">Show more</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">Show Less</a>
      </div>
      <div>{renderItems(props.itemData, props.item, props.itemDetailData)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemViewer;
```

Comment: you can use toggle state

Comment: v2103 did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a toggle state inside ItemViewer component, and using that value you can decide to show more or show less.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-59454586-toggle-show-more-less-nodu0)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const ItemViewer = ({ index, itemData, item }) => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  function renderItems(list) {
    if (list && list.length > 0) {
      if (list.length > 3 && toggle === false) {
        return renderList(list.slice(0, 3), "Show More");
      } else if (list.length > 3 && toggle === true) {
        return renderList(list, "Show Less");
      } else if (list.length === 3) {
        return renderList(list, "", false);
      }
    } else {
      return <p>No Items Found</p>;
    }
  }

  function renderList(list, buttonText, showButton = true) {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {list.map(function(item) {
            return <li key={item}>{item}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
        {showButton && (
          <div>
            <button onClick={toggleHandler}>{buttonText}</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

  const toggleHandler = () => {
    setToggle(prev => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span>
        {index}: {item}
      </span>
      <div>{renderItems(itemData)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemViewer;
```

Comment: @SuleymanShah Yeah checked it:) Works just fine. Thanks for your time

Comment: @v2103 you are welcome, can you mark it as answer? I think this is better than other answers.

Comment: @SuleymanShah, Can the button/link be kept inside of ItemViewer rather than inside different if  blocks? Just before renderItems function call

Comment: @v2103 do you want to move it inside the return function?

Comment: @v2103 but that button must repeat for all the items. It is fine to do like this.

Comment: yes ItemViewer will be called for each block. So is it possible to have it at only place ?

Comment: @v2103 ok I got it, let me try, I will inform you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204737/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-v2103).

Answer (score 1):

use component state and onClick listener:

```
  function renderItems(list, itemType) {
    if (list && list.length > 0 && this.state.showMore1) {
      ...

  <div>
    {" "}
    <a onClick={() => this.setState({ showMore1: !this.state.showMore1 )} href="#">Show {this.state.showMore1 ? 'Less' : 'More'}</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: still doesnt cover No data found case. Basically should cover all of this :1) when no data, just display "no data found" under that item 2) if items are less than 3 or equal to 3, hide show more/less ; just display the items 3) if items are greater than 3 , show first 3 items followed by show more/less(it should have the toggling between more/less)

Answer (score 1):

Use a handler for show events.

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-swirles-rchv0

```
  handleShowEvents(index) {
    let showMore = [...this.state.showMore];
    showMore[index] = !showMore[index];
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      showMore: showMore
    });
  }
```

Also, use a custom list builder.

```
 itemBuilder() {
    let items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.showMore.length; i++) {
      const item = `item${i + 1}`;
      if (this.state.showMore[i]) {
        items.push(
          <ItemViewer
            index={i}
            item={item}
            itemData={this.state.items[i]}
            handleShowEvents={this.handleShowEvents}
          />
        );
      } else {
        items.push(
          <ItemViewer
            index={i}
            item={item}
            itemData={this.state.items[i].slice(0, 3)}
            handleShowEvents={this.handleShowEvents}
          />
        );
      }
    }
    return items;
  }
```

Comment: should cover all of this :1) when no data, just display "no data found" under that item 2) if items are less than 3 or equal to 3, hide show more/less ; just display the items 3) if items are greater than 3 , show first 3 items followed by show more/less(it should have the toggling between more/less)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-shape-vinp6

Let me know if it works for you.

Happy Coding:)

Comment: @kookoos should cover all of this :1) when no data, just display "no data found" under that item
2) if items are less than 3 or equal to 3, hide show more/less ; just display the items
3) if items are greater than 3 , show first 3 items followed by show more/less(it should have the toggling between more/less)

Comment: Check out the updated sandbox and let me know if this is what you wanted:)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59458586/manipulating-a-complex-object-based-on-an-input-array