# Manipulating a complex object based on an input array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have an complex object and based on an input array I need to modify properties inside of this complex object. Illustration is shown below.
I need to group them based on field values and then add them to the "or" array of objects(if field value is same). If not same,directly add it to the "and" array of objects.
Need to read each field from the input array,and check if this is present inside "filter" of "filterObj" and if present add it to "and" else add it to the "or"

The format of both is shown below

```
//This is the source object where I need to add the below "arr" based on grouping

let filterObj = {
      "feature": "test",
      "filter": {
                 "and": [
                          { "field": "field1","value": "1"}
                        ]
                }
};

//This array needs to be added to above object by grouping based on field
let obj = [
             {"field" : "field1","value": "2"},
             {"field" : "field2","value": "3"},
             {"field" : "field2","value": "4"},
             {"field" : "field3","value" : "5"}
          ]
```

I want the output to be of following format:

```
var result = {
              "feature": "test",
              "filter": {
                 "and": [
                          {
                           "or" : [
                                    {"field": "field1","value": "1"},
                                    {"field": "field1", "value": "2"}
                                  ]                      
                          },
                          {
                            "or" : [
                                     {"field": "field2","value": "3"},
                                     {"field": "field2","value": "4"},
                                   ]                      
                          },
                          {  "field": "field3", "value": "5"}
                  ]
              } 
}

// The method that I have tried

filterObj.filter.and.or(...obj) ;// Does not work
```

Comment: Please not that your input has "fiedl2" and "field2" (two different). you meant it be same right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collect all same fields by a grouping and assign the values from grouping to `and` property.

```js
var filterObj = { feature: "test", filter: { and: [{ field: "field1", value: "1" }] } },
    obj = [{ field: "field1", value: "2" }, { field: "field2", value: "3" }, { field: "field2", value: "4" }, { field: "field3", value: "5" }],
    groups = obj.reduce(
        (r, o) => {
            if (r[o.field]) {
                if (!('or' in r[o.field])) r[o.field] = { or: [r[o.field]] };
                r[o.field].or.push(o);
            } else {
                r[o.field] = o;
            }
            return r;
        },
        (filterObj.filter.and || []).reduce((r, o) => {
            r['or' in o ? o.or[0].field : o.field] = o;
            return r;
        }, {}));

filterObj.filter.and = Object.values(groups);

console.log(filterObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Whenever it is empty it should sit inside "and". May be I forgot to tell this. Thanks again

Comment: You could take a default array, if no `and` is avalilable. please see edit.

Comment: it looks more like a new question than to discuss it here in the comment section. the most important question is *what is a duplicate*. you may address this in the question as well.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//This is the source object where I need to add the below "arr" based on grouping
let filterObj = {
  "feature": "test",
  "filter": {
    "and": [
      { "field": "field1", "value": "1" }
    ]
  }
};

//This array needs to be added to above object by grouping based on field
let obj = [
  { "field": "field1", "value": "2" },
  { "field": "field2", "value": "3" },
  { "field": "field2", "value": "4" },
  { "field": "field3", "value": "5" }
]
//obj = [{ "field": "field1", "value": "2" }]

let all_filters = [];
if (filterObj.filter.and && filterObj.filter.and.hasOwnProperty('or')) {
  all_filters = [...filterObj.filter.and.or];
} else if (filterObj.filter.and) {
  all_filters = [...filterObj.filter.and];
}
const all_objs = [...obj, ...all_filters];
// const all_objs = [...obj, ...filterObj.filter.and];
const uniqKeys = all_objs.reduce((acc, curr) => [...new Set([...acc, curr.field])], []);
const updateItems = uniqKeys.map(obj => {
  const filter_items = all_objs.filter(item => item.field === obj);
  let resultObj = {};
  if (filter_items && filter_items.length > 1) {
    resultObj.or = [...filter_items];
  } else if (filter_items && filter_items.length == 1) {
    resultObj = { ...filter_items[0] };
  }
  return resultObj;
})

var result = {...filterObj, filter: { and: [...updateItems] }};

console.log(result);
```

Please not that your input has "fiedl2" and "field2" (two different). I updated to same field name in the data here

Comment: why are you using Set over the fields?

Comment: @v2103, Set is helping to make unique set of keys(removing duplicates), So that we can group the filters

Comment: @v2103 sure, let me check when i am back

Comment: @v2013, I have updated the answers based and thanks for adding the tests. Hope the fix covers all cases.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Test case 6 does not seem covering entire thing up.https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-mirzakhani-pogpw?from-embed

Comment: Would you help me out here?

Comment: @v2103, Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-mirzakhani-pogpw-working-hif3o?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark. I just updated to fix case 6. There seems issue in building all_filters. Hope this helps. I have checked only case 6.

Comment: yes it would fail for others. https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-mirzakhani-pogpw-working-dpvis